# How to change dynamically height of textarea that have className?

Tags: javascript, height, textarea

I tried to autoheight the textarea that have an id.
using this code,

```
function init () {
var text = document.getElementById('id1');
function resize () {
    var clone = text.cloneNode();
    clone.className = 'clone';
    text.parentNode.insertBefore(clone, text);
    clone.style.height = 'auto';
    clone.value = text.value;
    text.style.height = (clone.scrollTop + clone.scrollHeight -20) + 'px';
    text.parentNode.removeChild(clone);
}
/* 0-timeout to get the already changed text */
function delayedResize () {
    window.setTimeout(resize, 0);
}
observe(text, 'change',  resize);
observe(text, 'cut',     delayedResize);
observe(text, 'paste',   delayedResize);
observe(text, 'drop',    delayedResize);
observe(text, 'keydown', delayedResize);

text.focus();
text.select();
resize();
}
```

I change the getElementByID by getElementsByClassName. Then clone it, but it is not working.

```
 var chs = document.getElementsByClassName("ch");
 for(var k  = 0; k < chs.length;k++){
             function resize () {
                var clone = chs[k].cloneNode();
                clone.className = 'clone';
                chs[k].parentNode.insertBefore(clone, chs[k]);
                clone.style.height = 'auto';
                clone.value = chs[k].value;
                chs[k].style.height = (clone.scrollTop + clone.scrollHeight -20) + 'px';
                chs[k].parentNode.removeChild(clone);
            }
            function delayedResize () {
                window.setTimeout(resize, 0);
            }
            observe(chs[k], 'change',  resize);
            observe(chs[k], 'cut',     delayedResize);
            observe(chs[k], 'paste',   delayedResize);
            observe(chs[k], 'drop',    delayedResize);
            observe(chs[k], 'keydown', delayedResize);
            chs[k].focus();
            chs[k].select();
            resize();
    }
```

The error is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cloneNode' of undefinedindex.html:253 resize

All I need is make all textarea dynamically change height. Like FB feed textarea.

Comment: First of all you shouldn't declare functions inside a loop; Second, as `rezied` is an event, you should use `this` because `chs[k]` won't be available when the event is fired. `k` is a local variable whithin the loop.

Comment: No. ch[k] is out side the loop.

Comment: But `k` is in the loop.

Comment: i mean .ch i s outside. getElementsByClassName i think returns like an array of elements. so i use loop